# Postgres, Update TIMESTAMP to current date but preserve time of day

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my Postgres database, I have the following table:

```
SELECT start_at, end_at FROM schedules;

+---------------------+---------------------+
| start_at            | end_at              |
|---------------------+---------------------|
| 2016-09-05 16:30:00 | 2016-09-05 17:30:00 |
| 2016-09-05 17:30:00 | 2016-09-05 18:30:00 |
| 2017-08-13 03:00:00 | 2017-08-13 07:00:00 |
| 2017-08-13 03:00:00 | 2017-08-13 07:00:00 |
| 2017-08-13 18:42:26 | 2017-08-13 21:30:46 |
| 2017-08-10 00:00:00 | 2017-08-10 03:30:00 |
| 2017-08-09 18:00:00 | 2017-08-10 03:00:00 |
| 2017-08-06 23:00:00 | 2017-08-07 03:00:00 |
| 2017-08-07 01:00:00 | 2017-08-07 03:48:20 |
| 2017-08-07 01:00:00 | 2017-08-07 03:48:20 |
| 2017-08-07 18:05:00 | 2017-08-07 20:53:20 |
| 2017-08-07 14:00:00 | 2017-08-08 01:00:00 |
| 2017-08-07 18:00:00 | 2017-08-07 20:48:20 |
| 2017-08-08 08:00:00 | 2017-08-09 00:00:00 |
| 2017-08-09 21:30:00 | 2017-08-10 00:18:20 |
| 2017-08-13 03:53:26 | 2017-08-13 06:41:46 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Assume I also have an ID column, what I want to do is update all the start and end times to be for today (now), what is the most efficient SQL to accomplish this? My table could have millions of rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the best I  can think of is this:

```
 update schedules 
    set start_at = current_date + start_at::time
      , end_at = current_date + end_at::time 
    WHERE start_at::date <> current_date
       or end_at::date <> current_date;
```

The arithmetic is fast compared to accessing the rows.
if not all rows need updating, the where clause will help efficiency. Updates are expensive.